# libcurl: Get result of libcurl requested via CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS

Tags: libcurl, ocsp

Using libcurl I'm sending an HTTP request to a server with enabled OCSP stapling by using `curl_easy_setopt(<my handle>, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS, 1L)`.

A libcurl response code of 0 is a necessary condition for a failed certificate status verification, but it is not a sufficient condition as well. 
So how do I check if the request failed due to a failed certificate status verification?

Of course, curl's error buffer provides a reason for the failed request, but I do not want to search the error buffer for occurrences of curl's OSCP error messages.

Instead, I would like to directly extract curl's info I have requested by setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS` (as it is possible for several other curl infos).

Am I just overlooking it or is there no direct way to evaluate the certification status verification?

Answer (score 0):

While time has passed I again came across the need for a solution for the addressed problem and I found some ways I could go for solving this issue but they seem quite inappropriate to me:
For instance I could directly check the OCSP relevant data of the SSL object belonging to the reuqest:

```
const struct curl_tlssessioninfo* info = NULL;
CURLcode res = curl_easy_getinfo(handle, CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR, &info);
SSL* ssl = (SSL*)info->internals;
// check ssl->tlsext_ocsp_resp
```

Or I could make checks just as they are done in the libcurl code in function verifystatus in vtls/openssl.c:

```
...
long len = SSL_get_tlsext_status_ocsp_resp(BACKEND->handle, &status);
rsp = d2i_OCSP_RESPONSE(NULL, &p, len);
....
```

Best for me would be to be able to directly call the verifystatus function in libcurls openssl.c but it's not accessible from the "outside", probably for a good reason.

Does anybody have an idea of how one can and should directly access the OCSP response?
I'm also happy about comments on my suggestions of solving that issue.